# Flot Multi Axes Bar Chart with orderbars and categories plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, bar-chart, flot

I've created a bar chart with Flot that uses two sets of data on one chart. Each set has it's own y-axis. I want the bars to be placed side-by-side, however when the chart is drawn, they overlap.

[image]

I tried using the orderbars plugin like so

```
{ data: d1, bars: {order: 1}, label: "Merchant Vol",  },
{ data: d2, bars: {order: 2}, label: "Residual Pmt", yaxis: 2}
```

but this results in the bars not rendering. I also use the categories mode / plugin.

I suspect it's a problem with using two y-axes. Is there a way to plot bar charts with multiple axes without the bars overlapping? Fiddle with code [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/o6sz0bwy/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The orderbars plugin is not compatible with the categories plugin. It works by moving each bar a little from its original position (e.g. the bar at x value 1 is shifted to 0.9 for one data series and to 1.1 for the other). That doesn't work when you have `Jun-16` as x value.

The solution is to remove the categories plugin, use numeric x values and set the x axis ticks yourself. See the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o6sz0bwy/4/).

[image]

Comment: Everything is okay. But how can we use only one y-axis instead of two.?

Comment: How to show the amount on tooltip through this plugin for this type of chart?

Comment: @ThamaraiT: You should ask a new question (which should include all relevant information and code of your problem).

Comment: I don't have a problem, first. Just I have a requirement to show data in single y-axis from two data series. That's all. Anyhow if it is required, I will post a new question.